# Splitting of words in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame, I wanted to break the text in words, but I am getting a square bracket in between the set of words. I am using the code mentioned below.

```
for index1, row1 in df.iterrows():

   words1 = set([word for word in str(row1.values).split()])
```

I am creating a DataFrame from a CSV file then breaking it into words.

```
0,"['cell', 'study', 'protein', 'result', 'effect', 'gene', 'treatment', 'may', 'level', 'mouse']"
```

Output-->

```
{'effect', 'result', 'treatment',  'protein', 'may', 'level', 'cell', 'mouse', 'study', 'gene'}
```

but the desired output is

```
{'effect', 'result', 'treatment', '0', 'protein', 'may', 'level', 'cell', 'mouse', 'study', 'gene'}
```

Why I am getting a list `[0', 'protein', 'may', 'level', "'cell", "mouse']` in the output?

Please suggest the possible ways to tokenize it.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @Tomothy32 Sorry, Please have a look

Comment: @GAUTAMKISHORESHAHI just provide input dataframe and expected output.

Comment: @meW input is in DataFrame [0 cell study protein result effect gene treatment may level mouse] and output should be {'effect', 'result', 'treatment', '0', 'protein', 'may', 'level', 'cell', 'mouse', 'study', 'gene'}

Comment: Your output looks like a `set`. But in question put the input in a dataframe structure to understand what you intend to get.

Comment: @meW Thanks, I have edited the question. yes the output is a set, but in my case, I am getting a list inside the set, can you please tell me the reason?

Comment: There's no list in the set, look closely. It's a square bracket inside a string.

Comment: @Tomothy32 Why am I getting this bracket? Can you please suggest me to remove this bracket?

Comment: What is your **exact** input? Its impossible to tell why you are getting the bracket if you do not provide the exact input. Also the quotes enclosing that bracketed value is wrong in your output

Comment: @ycx Please have a look over the question again, I have updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
data['column'] = data['column'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x)))
```

Comment: The solution works for me and there was no column name given, so I think its okay.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `str(row1.values)`, you convert a list of words into a string that looks like a list. When you then apply `.split()`, it splits the string with white spaces. Clearly, square brackets are not white spaces, and they are left as is.

If you want to convert lists into sets (and that's what you appear to be doing, presumably to eliminate duplicates), simply apply `set()` to each row:

```
words1 = set(row1.values)
```

However, most probably you want to do this to the whole dataframe at once:

```
df.apply(set, axis=1)
```